# IRT monotonicity

Tags: assumptions, item-response-theory

I am trying to analyse data from a questionnaire containing 24 items using a 2pl IRT.  Responses are provided on yes-no format.  How can I examine the assumption of monotonicity in IRT for binary data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically two approaches to doing this in the literature: semi-parametric modelling via flexible IRT models such as splines, and fully non-parametric IRT models with techniques such as kernel smoothing and Mokken analyses. As well, item-fit statistics may be helpful here to detect the issue because if you initially fit a 2PL model, and fit statistics suggest this model is poor, then you know something is amiss.

The splines approach is generally model-based, and therefore can be estimated by efficient algorithms such as MML, while the non-parametric approach is generally cheaper computationally but less flexible modelling-wise (i.e., has more difficulty dealing with missing data, and assumes a non-parametric form for all items, thereby reducing the use of prior information and stability).

The splines approach works much like it does in linear regression with splines: smooth polynomial functions with a number of knots are pre-selected and used to estimate a non-linear but smooth functional form. This has the benefit of providing isolated modelling conditions, where say only 1 item is fitted via a spline model while the rest of the items are from the 2PL family. It also generalises to multidimensional models easily because it is model based.

The non-parametric approach (found historically in programs such as **TestGraph**) assumes that the total sum-score is a sufficient statistic for the latent trait parameter ($\theta$) and then uses a kernel smoothing approach to approximate the functional form.

Below is a very simple example in R using tools from the **mirt** package for a splines model, and **KernSmoothIRT** for the non-parametric IRT model. A misfitting quadratic response model is included for item 21, which demonstrate a rather strong non-monotone response function.

```R
library(mirt)
library(KernSmoothIRT)

P <- function(Theta){exp(Theta^2 * 1.2 - 1) / (1 + exp(Theta^2 * 1.2 - 1))}

#make some data
set.seed(1)
a <- matrix(rlnorm(20, meanlog=0, sdlog = .1),ncol=1)
d <- matrix(rnorm(20),ncol=1)
Theta <- matrix(rnorm(2000))
items <- rep('2PL', 20)
ps <- P(Theta)
baditem <- numeric(2000)
for(i in 1:2000)
    baditem[i] <- sample(c(0,1), 1, prob = c(1-ps[i], ps[i]))
data <- cbind(simdata(a,d, 2000, items, Theta=Theta), baditem=baditem)

mod <- mirt(data, 1, itemtype = '2PL')
itemfit(mod) 

      item    S_X2 df.S_X2 p.S_X2
1   Item_1  11.684      15  0.703
2   Item_2  19.086      16  0.264
3   Item_3  11.863      16  0.753
4   Item_4  15.095      16  0.518
5   Item_5  13.842      16  0.610
6   Item_6  13.823      16  0.612
7   Item_7  12.568      16  0.704
8   Item_8  19.348      16  0.251
9   Item_9  18.300      16  0.307
10 Item_10  22.156      16  0.138
11 Item_11  15.517      15  0.415
12 Item_12  16.236      16  0.437
13 Item_13  16.483      16  0.420
14 Item_14  10.133      16  0.860
15 Item_15  17.527      16  0.352
16 Item_16  11.727      16  0.763
17 Item_17  25.022      16  0.069
18 Item_18  24.052      16  0.088
19 Item_19  12.219      15  0.662
20 Item_20  13.029      15  0.600
21 baditem 233.465      18  0.000
```

Item 21 fits very poorly; hence, 2PL not a good fit. Now, fit item 21 with a spline model, and plot to see the relationship.

```R
itemtype <- c(rep('2PL', 20), 'spline')
mod2 <- mirt(data, 1, itemtype=itemtype, TOL=2e-4)
itemplot(mod2, 21)
```

[image: splineIRT]

Now with kernel smoothing for each item.

```R
ks <- ksIRT(data, format=2, key=1)
plot(ks, item=21)
```

[image: ksIRT]

Comment: Dear Phil, Thank you very much for your detailed response.  You ' been very helpfull.  I actually use mirt and it is really an excellent library.

Comment: @Nikos great, glad to hear it. If you believe this answer sufficiently addresses your question then feel free to upvote and mark it as an accepted answer.